# How to wrap each line with a div in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a text paragraph.

I would like to wrap each line with a div.

For example if the text string looks like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Nam eget lectus porta metus aliquam tincidunt sed vel enim.
```

Then I would like to wrap it like this

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div> 
<div>consectetur adipiscing elit.</div> 
<div><br/></div>
<div>Nam eget lectus porta metus aliquam tincidunt sed vel enim.</div>
```

Can someone tell me what is the proper way?

Thanks

Comment: Is the text stored in a variable or a file? What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidCullen Its stored in a variable. And answer helped. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `bytes.Buffer` and `bufio.NewScanner`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"
import "bufio"
import "bytes"

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nam eget lectus porta metus aliquam tincidunt sed vel enim.`)

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        s := scanner.Text()
        if len(s) == 0 {
            s = `<br/>`
        }
        buf.WriteString(`<div>` + s + `</div>
`)
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

output:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
<div>consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div><br/></div>
<div>Nam eget lectus porta metus aliquam tincidunt sed vel enim.</div>
```

---

You may use `bytes.Buffer` and `html/template`,
but you have `<div></div>` instead of `<div><br/></div>`, then you may use

```
s = strings.Replace(s, `<div></div>`, `<div><br/></div>`, -1)
```

like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "bytes"
import "html/template"
import "strings"

func main() {
    r := []string{`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,`,
        `consectetur adipiscing elit.`,
        ``,
        `Nam eget lectus porta metus aliquam tincidunt sed vel enim.`}
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    t := template.Must(template.New("template").Parse("{{range .}}<div>{{.}}</div>\n{{end}}"))
    t.Execute(buf, r)
    s := buf.String()
    s = strings.Replace(s, `<div></div>`, `<div><br/></div>`, -1)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

output:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
<div>consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div><br/></div>
<div>Nam eget lectus porta metus aliquam tincidunt sed vel enim.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the part of generating the HTML snippet from a slice of lines, you should use the following code, which takes care of properly escaping the HTML.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    data := []string{
        "first",
        "second",
        "<style>body{background-color:lime;}</style>",
        "<script>alert('evil')</script>",
    }
    htmlTemplate := "{{range .}}<div>{{.}}</div>\n{{end}}"

    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(htmlTemplate))
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
}
```